# How to put textview on top of listview

Tags: android-layout

How do I have textview on top of my listview (code shown below)? I tried many ways of placing the textview but it just does not appear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/nameheader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <ListView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is problem ? its showing me on my machine.

Comment: I tried it again...doesn't work for me.

Comment: have you tried using layout_weight ?

Comment: please show screen shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code just add `android:text="Maulik Dodia"`. I have just copy your code added **TWO LINES** to it. One is **above one**, Second is `android:entries="@array/names"`. I have also added `<string-array name="names">
        <item>Maulik</item>
        <item>Maulik1</item>
        <item>Maulik2</item>
        <item>Maulik3</item>
    </string-array>` to **strings.xml**

And It worked for me in preview of Android Studio as well as in Emulator.
Below is my code as well as Screen Shots.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.XXXXXXXXXX.sotestingapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameheader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Maulik Dodia"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/names"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">SOTestingApp</string>
    <string-array name="names">
        <item>Maulik</item>
        <item>Maulik1</item>
        <item>Maulik2</item>
        <item>Maulik3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

[image: Android Studio Preview Image]
[image: Emulator Output]

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/nameheader"
        android:text="Hello Android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please check this if it works.

Comment: Error:(4, 24) String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap_parent').